# Storing audio paths and playing it on web page

Tags: php, mysql, html, audio

What I'm working on involves many short audio clips to be played on the webpage.
I know that the best way to play an audio file is to use an audio tag, and also storing the audio files in a local storage and calling the path in the database.

My main question is that how do I store the audio file path in the database column and what do I have to do to be able to play the file?

Also, I am not sure how does that file path interaction with database works, can anyone enlighten me?

This is also because I am doing something like a spelling bee whereby there will be a play button or a text that the user can click and a sound will be heard which is next to the question and then they will have to type their answer.

What matters for me now is in making the audio feature work.

Any input will be GREATLY appreciated.

Comment: You can create 2 tables. One with settings, storing the path to the audio files folder and one with the names of audio files. When you do the query in your php file you will concatenate the path to audio file name and put them inside audio tag. You should try yourself and post the code where you have difficulties.

Comment: Hey, before you start to work, remember that `NEVER NEVER NEVER store paths into DB, just store file names in DB` because whenever you will move your project to any other location/server, you will have a lots of problems

Comment: @Allkin Sorry I am a beginner and just getting started is it possible for you to help with providing some codes that I can work on? Greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

I will post a simple example and then you can extend it to whatever you need.
First you need to copy the audio file to a folder in your public html directory, let's say audio.
After that you need to create a database and open a connection to it.
You can read about it in [PHP Documentation](http://php.net/manual/ro/mysqli.quickstart.connections.php).
Here is an example of a php file that connects to a database store the filename and then gets it.
Example of database structure:

`id | audio_name
 1    audio1.mp3`

```
<?php
$con = new mysqli("localhost", "user", "password", "database");
if ($con->connect_errno) {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: (" . $con->connect_errno . ") " . $con->connect_error;
}

//We define a constant with the path to audio 
define('PATH','audio/');

//We store the audio file name in database
$result = $con->query("INSERT INTO table(audio_name) VALUES('audio1.mp3')");

//To get values from database you can do this
$audiomp3 = $con->query("SELECT audio_name FROM table WHERE audio_name = 'audio1.mp3'")->fetch_object()->audio_name;

//Full path to audio file
$audiomp3 = PATH . $audiomp3;

//And we create a audio element
$element = "";
$element .= "<audio controls>";
$element .= "<source src='$audiomp3' type='audio/ogg'>";
$element .= "Your browser does not support the audio element.";
$element .= "</audio>";

//Displaying audio element
echo $element;
```

> Remember this is a base example!