# Is it possible to display my audio file from database to html <audio> tag?

Tags: php, html, database

I have my audio path stored in database, I followed the example given from this page,
[Storing audio paths and playing it on web page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31111630/storing-audio-paths-and-playing-it-on-web-page). However, from that example it creates new audio element in php section. I have my php here:

```
$audiomp3 = $array[$counter]['path'];

$element = "";
$element .= "<audio controls";
$element .= "<source src = '$audiomp3' type ='audio/mpeg'>";
$element .= "Your browser does not support audio element.";
$element .="</audio>";
```

This creates an audio element in my page but what happening is I already have an `audio` tag in my html:

```
<audio id="player" controls>
  <source src = "audio/audio1.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>
```

My page ended up showing 2 audio elements. Instead of create new element, is it possible to modify the existing `audio` tag in html ? I've tried changing the source to `source src ="$audiomp3"` and `source src="$path"`, didn't work.

Comment: You could remove the other audio element from your code, and you're done. However, if you want to modify an existing element in a web page you have to look into Javascript and AJAX. JavaScript is a client-side scripting language while PHP is a server-side scripting language.

Comment: Thank you, guess ill have to start reading at AJAX..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the easy way is to hide the audio player when you show the one générated by php.

```
$audiomp3 = $array[$counter]['path'];

$element = "";
$element .= "<audio controls";
$element .= "<source src = '$audiomp3' type ='audio/mpeg'>";
$element .= "Your browser does not support audio element.";
$element .="</audio>";
$element .="<script>document.getElementById('player').style.display = 'none';</script>";
```

Comment: Sorry i think i didnt not deliver my question clear enough, I needed the audio from php because its connected to database, but now that I know i can also use getelementbyid to do styling, guess ill just remove another one and style this one. thanks